# how to pass special characters in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jsp

How to pass special characters variables i in ajax call and get the values in spring controller. if file `name="##@jsuduu"`

```
function deleeteimg(){
    var filename=$("#filenm").text();
    alert(filename);
    //var filename=$(this).attr("data-id");
    var url="/myuploads/deleteFile.html?filename="filename;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        contentType: 'html',
        success: function(response) {
             window.location.href="/myuploads/showUploads.html";
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: They're URL-encoded.

Comment: `encodeURIComponent(filename)`

Comment: You're missing a `+` sign here : `?filename=" + filename;`

Comment: hi pawel,   this method already tried  but  its not working  error in ajax url tell me alternative way

Answer (score 9):

Use this following methods it works

```
encodeURI()
encodeURIComponent()

type: "POST",
url: "ajax/save",
data:"Name="+encodeURIComponent("##@jsuduu")
```

Comment: we decode it with js, now how would one decode them with PHP?

Answer (score 2):

The `encodeURIComponent()` encode special characters. In addition, it encodes the following characters: , / ? : @ & = + $ #

You can try adding the special characters inside the `encodeURIComponent()` method and it works. Following is a sample.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'removeFile?removeFilePath=' + encodeURIComponent("C:///YO/Ed/PO/")
        data: {},
        dataType: 'json',
```