# how to javascript fetch a file with # in its name

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have a file called 'c#5.mp3' when I try to do a `fetch` on it the actual request that sent is for 'c'. I get why this is happening but is there an option I can set to suppress the behavior. I know I could change the file name, but lets suppose that the file name is not changeable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to pass special characters in ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34411417/how-to-pass-special-characters-in-ajax-call). TL;DR `fetch(\`https://example.com/${encodeURIComponent("c#5.mp3")}\`)`

Comment: Change the file name feels like the best option here frankly